# Meta_query on same meta key, with diffrenct values

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, user-meta, meta-value

i'm trying to get_users with the meta_query where i need to find users where either they don't have the meta key, or it is blank.

It seems like everywhere i look, i should be able to use the OR on the relation and then use the same meta key, but how ever i set it up, it does not work.

My code:

```
$ors[] = array(
   'key'   => 'death_date',
   'compare' => '=',
   'value' => '',
   'type' => 'NUMERIC'                    
);
$ors[] = array(
   'key'   => 'death_date',
   'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'                    
);

$args = array(
   'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'or',
   $ors,
));

$return = get_users($args);
```

Both of them work separately, but not together.

Comment: note that `NOT EXISTS` style queries are very slow/expensive on the database.  If you can, always  give users a death date, even if it's a special value such as the 1st January 30,000AD, and do it via a filter. Then you c an avoid these kinds of queries entirely